# Do I even need a bearer token, if i have a csrf token?

Tags: php, laravel, token, csrf

I am developing a Laravel API and I wanted to use a bearer token to safely communicate with the VueJS Frontend. A friend of mine then told me, that this would be unnecessary, because Laravel already uses the CSRF Token to shield against XSS-Attacks.

So, is my token based authentication basically useless if I already use the csrf token and why?

Comment: an access token is different from a csrf token. The access token gives you authorization to use something, while CSRF is a protection mechanism to secure state-changing forms, which is tightly related to the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about two different things here.
A Bearer token is for authentication to an API for example, a CSRF Token is for protecting against cross-side-request-forgery attacks.

The bearer token is your login token to an external api-service like a passport or member-card, so you are granted access to this external service. The token also tells the server who the person/machine accessing the resource is, so the server can decide if they have the correct permissions.

The CSRF token protects you from request forgery, meaning someone making a request to your server from an external server or tool. The only thing a CSRF token tells you is that the request came from someone using your site, it doesn't tell you who that person is or what permissions they have.

I hope you understand. Maybe you should study the CSRF Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

And some info for bearer tokens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: I think he knows this but is wondering if he can use the same token for both purposes. Which he really shouldn't, it's not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely add some kind of stateless token bases authentication, considering the fact the csrf token is only for shielding against XSS-Attacks, not for authenticating and authorising an User based on role and permission.

Comment: CSRF tokens are for shielding against CSRF attacks. Not XSS attacks.